# Operações com Data Frame

Tags: r, data.frame

Preciso fazer como a imagem abaixo. Como seria? Já consegui isolar as linhas que são somente zeros em todas as colunas com uso do `subset(Base, VALOR1==0&VALOR2==0&VALOR3==0&VALOR4==0)`, porém não consigo fazer um tratamento entre o data frame que contém apenas zeros do data frame completo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
structure(list(CADASTRO = structure(c(8L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("ANTONIA", "ANTONIO", "FABIO", "FILOMENA", 
"MARCUS", "MARIA", "MONICA", "TEREZA", "THIAGO"), class = "factor"), 
    VALOR1 = c(0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 45L, 0L, 0L), VALOR2 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 30L, 32L, 0L, 23L), VALOR3 = c(0L, 20L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 45L, 12L, 0L, 21L), VALOR4 = c(0L, 45L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    90L, 22L, 0L, 100L), VALOR5 = structure(1:9, .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"), class = "factor"), 
    VALOR6 = structure(c(8L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
    "*", "1", "2.2", "3", "D", "NOK", "OK"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

```
> base
  CADASTRO VALOR1 VALOR2 VALOR3 VALOR4 VALOR5 VALOR6
1   TEREZA      0      0      0      0      A     OK
2  ANTONIA     10      0     20     45      B    NOK
3    MARIA      0      0      0      0      C     OK
4   THIAGO      0      0      0      0      D       
5   MONICA      0      0      0      0      E      1
6    FABIO     20     30     45     90      F      D
7   MARCUS     45     32     12     22      G    2.2
8 FILOMENA      0      0      0      0      H      3
9  ANTONIO      0     23     21    100      I      *

> library(dplyr)
> dados = base %>% select('CADASTRO','VALOR1','VALOR2','VALOR3','VALOR4')
> dados
  CADASTRO VALOR1 VALOR2 VALOR3 VALOR4
1   TEREZA      0      0      0      0
2  ANTONIA     10      0     20     45
3    MARIA      0      0      0      0
4   THIAGO      0      0      0      0
5   MONICA      0      0      0      0
6    FABIO     20     30     45     90
7   MARCUS     45     32     12     22
8 FILOMENA      0      0      0      0
9  ANTONIO      0     23     21    100

> base_0 = subset(dados, VALOR1==0&VALOR2==0&VALOR3==0&VALOR4==0)
> base_0
  CADASTRO VALOR1 VALOR2 VALOR3 VALOR4
1   TEREZA      0      0      0      0
3    MARIA      0      0      0      0
4   THIAGO      0      0      0      0
5   MONICA      0      0      0      0
8 FILOMENA      0      0      0      0
```

Comment: Olá Fabio, mostre como seu código está até o momento para que possamos te ajudar de uma maneira melhor.

Comment: forneça os dados na pergunta pfv: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r

Comment: Duvida melhor apresentada!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar a mesma função `subset()` com o operador `!` que significa uma negação. Mais informações [aqui](https://bookdown.org/wevsena/curso_de_r/Curso_de_R.nb.html#operacoes-logicas).

```
dados = subset(dados, !(VALOR1==0&VALOR2==0&VALOR3==0&VALOR4==0))
```

Answer (score 0):

So para complementar a resposta acima. Podemos fazer isso de forma dinâmica (sem precisar nomear as colunas). Isso pode ser útil se você tiver um número grande de colunas ou se não tiver certeza da natureza das colunas. No seu exemplo, você está interessado somente nas colunas que têm como classe `integer`. Portanto, podemos primeiro filtrar quais colunas satisfazem essa condição:

```r
cols <- sapply(dados, function(x) is.numeric(x))

cols <- names(which(cols==TRUE))
```

Inspecionando o objeto `cols`:

```
> cols
[1] "VALOR1" "VALOR2" "VALOR3" "VALOR4"
```

Agora vamos usar `lapply()` e `Reduce()`. `lapply()` por que precisamos de um objeto de tipo `list` em `Reduce()`. `Reduce()` irá combinar os objetos desta `list` um por um sucessivamente através da função especificada no seu primeiro argument `.f`. Portanto:

```r
dados[!Reduce(`&`, lapply(cols, function(x) dados[[x]] == 0)), ]
```

Retorna:

```
  CADASTRO VALOR1 VALOR2 VALOR3 VALOR4 VALOR5 VALOR6
2  ANTONIA     10      0     20     45      B    NOK
6    FABIO     20     30     45     90      F      D
7   MARCUS     45     32     12     22      G    2.2
9  ANTONIO      0     23     21    100      I      *
```

Como explicado antes, a grande vantagem desse método é que ele generaliza para qualquer `data.frame` na qual você deseja aplicar a condição (no seu caso, retorne as linhas que não tenham todas as suas colunas de tipo `integer` preenchidas com `0`).